# Displaying list horizontally

Tags: c++, c++11, hash

I recently came across [this](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/WqMyTHiyA3) geeksforgeeks program of **Hashing** with **separate chaining**:

But I am unable to understand it's code for `displayHash()` member function.

My questions are:

1. Is there really a need for using **auto** type (as code works fine with **int** type too)?
2. How is list being displayed horizontally using `auto x:table[i]`(syntax not clear to me)?

Helpful links to documents are appreciated.

Comment: 1: No. 2: Range-based for loop.

Comment: @Sneftel Please can you give more detailed explanation to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This all has to do with C++11 additions (which are not new at this point, it has been more than 7 years).

`auto` is not an actual type, it is deduced to one. So it is never necessary, albeit very useful. If for example you replace `int index = hashFunction(key);` with `auto index = hashFunction(key);`, you don't actually change anything semantically: `auto` is deduced to `int` because of the return type of `hashFunction`.
See [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto).

The line `for (int x : table[i])` is called a "range-based for loop" and is equivalent to the following (at least in this case):

```
{
    auto && __range = table[i];
    auto __begin = __range.begin();
    auto __end = __range.end();
    for ( ; __begin != __end; ++__begin) {
        int x = *__begin;
        // loop body
    }
}
```

See [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

Comment: Is there any alternative to using this ''range-based for loop''?

Comment: Yes, the equivalent snippet I included. You can also do something not entirely equivalent but good enough, like `for (auto it = table[i].begin(); it != table[i].end(); ++it) { // use *it instead of x }`.

Comment: Yeah I was too thinking this.Got it.

Comment: 'It's never necessary'. It is when the actual type is unknown, as is the case with lambda functions, for instance, `auto f = []() { ... }`. auto is the only possible type here.